# Web3J "transaction.getTo()" returns null if sent to contract

Tags: java, ethereum, web3-java

I'm currently running a full node and am trying to loop through some transactions. Whenever I do so with Web3j and use the `EthBlock.TransactionObject` and I get to a transaction that contains a contract ([Like this one](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9e7b5966b33b4393f250bfcf45eed7751d44981b6d8dec9422a0bd2a2c698306)) and use the `.getTo()` function it returns a null value. Is there any way for me to retrieve the contract address?

EDIT:
This is the code im using to get the transaction

```
EthBlock.Block block = web3.ethGetBlockByNumber(DefaultBlockParameter.valueOf(BigInteger.valueOf(1397553)), true).send().getBlock();
List<EthBlock.TransactionResult> transactionResults = block.getTransactions();
transactionResults.forEach(tx -> {
   EthBlock.TransactionObject transaction = (EthBlock.TransactionObject) tx.get();
   System.out.println(transaction.getCreates());
});
```

This returns a "null"

Answer (score 0):

When a transaction creates a contract, the `to` field is empty by design (of the Ethereum network).

To get the contract address that the transaction creates, use the [getCreates()](https://javadoc.io/static/org.web3j/core/4.5.3/org/web3j/protocol/core/methods/response/Transaction.html#getCreates--) method.

Comment: This also returned Null for me. both the getCreates and getTo return null. Is this maybe because the node is a full one and not an archive one?

Comment: I have updated the post so you can see the code i used

Comment: @Rodarg I'm not that well versed in the Java version of `web3` so I'm not able to debug it in more depth. In my experience, in the **JavaScript** `web3js` you'd use the property `contractAddress` that returns the contract address every time when a contract is created (and the `to` field is empty). But hopefully someone else is going to have a better answer.

Comment: One more idea. It is possible that the transaction has been reverted and no contract was created from this particular tx. So the `to` field is `Null`, but also no contract was created - which would possibly make the value of `creates` property `Null` as well.

Comment: Well looking at the transaction i linked it seems like the transaction is valid so dont really know what im doing wrong here